# How to export to PDF with blocks that respect indentation AND subscripts?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

How can I export so that both subscripts and indentation are respected? For example, using QUOTE will respect special characters like subscripts, but will ignore spacing. The opposite is true of EXAMPLE or SRC blocks.

```
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
let x_m be the constraints over x_n variables

set all x_n = false

for x_i \in right-hand sides of x_m while equation X is FALSE:\\
   x_i = true\\
   if X is true, return TRUE\\
return FALSE
#+END_QUOTE
```

Answer (score 1):

Export to pdf is handled by LaTeX, and `org-mode` only manages a small subset of the possible options. `EXAMPLE` blocks are exported as `verbatim` environments, which will change none of your text - it respects all your whitespace, but will not process any macros (such as your subscripts).

On the other hand, `quote` blocks are exported as `quote` environments. These do process macros, but impose LaTeX spacing algorithms.

There is no halfway. If you were writing in pure LaTeX, you would have all kinds of options. `org-mode` doesn't support them, but you can include raw LaTeX in your org-mode file, and it will be respected during export (as long as it's not in an `example` block). This being the case, you can insert a bit of LaTeX to get what you want. A relatively simple approach would be:

```
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
let x_m be the constraints over x_n variables

set all x_n = false

for x_i \in right-hand sides of x_m while equation X is FALSE:\\
\hspace*{2em}  x_i = true\\
\hspace*{2em}  if X is true, return TRUE\\
return FALSE
#+END_QUOTE
```

The output looks fine, but it's a bit ugly in your org mode file.

Comment: I can readily include an `#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex`. Even in Latex, though, I was hoping there was something better than individual hspace commands and line breaks...

Comment: This is how I'd do it in LaTeX as well. By design, LaTeX doesn't make it easy to manage white space manually. Another alternative might be using an align environment or something similar, but that puts you into math-mode.